# nix-env and nix-shell have different versions of snap

Tags: haskell, nix, nixos

I was following directions on [reflex-platfrom project development](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-platform/blob/develop/docs/project-development.md),trying to test [servant-reflex](https://github.com/imalsogreg/servant-reflex) as a submodule.

[My project](https://github.com/YuMingLiao/haskell_code) is here.

In my `backend.cabal`, I have a built-depend:
 `snap >= 1.1.1.0 && < 1.2`

When I `nix-shell -A shells.ghc --run "cabal new-build all"`, it tries to install heist-1.0.1.0 and snap-1.0.0.2, then failed at

```
Configuring heist-1.0.1.0...
Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:
aeson >=0.6 && <1.2
```

To see what in my nixos-unstable, I:

```
`nix-channel --list`
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable

`nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages.aeson`
warning: Nix search path entry '/home/demo/.nix-defexpr/channels' does not exist, ignoring
haskellPackages.aeson  aeson-1.2.4.0

`nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages.snap`
warning: Nix search path entry '/home/demo/.nix-defexpr/channels' does not exist, ignoring
haskellPackages.snap  snap-1.1.0.0

`nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages.heist`
warning: Nix search path entry '/home/demo/.nix-defexpr/channels' does not exist, ignoring
haskellPackages.heist  heist-1.0.1.2
```

Q: Why does nix-shell install heist-1.0.1.0 and snap-1.0.0.2, instead of heist-1.0.1.2 and snap-1.1.0.0, which then can dependent on aeson-1.2.4.0?

Comment: Your `default.nix` is using the `project` attribute from `reflex-platform`. As it happens, `reflex-platform` supplies its own preferred version of `nixpkgs`, since it relies on some patches that aren't available yet upstream.

What you can do for heist is to jailbreak it (artificially strip the version bounds) in `default.nix`. This can be a good stopgap while waiting for the proper updates to get upstream:

```
...
packages = {
  common = ./common;
  heist = pkgs.haskell.lib.doJailbreak pkgs.heist;
  backend = ./backend;
...
```

Comment: @ImAlsoGreg Thx again! Now I add this line. And after I add back servant-snap or snap, nix-shell tells me `attribute 'heist' missing`. I don't know where to start. Do you happen to know where to look at this issue?

Comment: ok, I just need to change pkgs.heist to pkgs.haskellPackages.heist and get the attribute. Now it is compiling. Thx! Plz let me give credit to your "doJailbreak" answer in this common "version conflict" problem.

Comment: Oh, no.. now it's ... `building '/nix/store/04s6cca0b5q00n0qqp8h1kwzqrbiz1f5-cabal2nix-heist.drv'...
installing
*** found zero or more than one cabal file ([]). Exiting.
builder for '/nix/store/04s6cca0b5q00n0qqp8h1kwzqrbiz1f5-cabal2nix-heist.drv' failed with exit code 1
error: build of '/nix/store/04s6cca0b5q00n0qqp8h1kwzqrbiz1f5-cabal2nix-heist.drv' failed
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)`

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer from elvishjerricco on IRC #nixos.

> To `doJailbreak` heist, you'd use the `overrides` argument to
>   `project`
>
> `packages` is for just declaring directories that you want to turn
>   into haskell packages; it'll run cabal2nix for you. `overrides` is for
>   doing derivation changes to the haskell package set.

## default.nix

```
(import ./reflex-platform {}).project ({ pkgs, ... }: {

  overrides = self: super: {
   heist = pkgs.haskell.lib.doJailbreak super.heist;
   map-syntax = pkgs.haskell.lib.doJailbreak super.map-syntax;
  };

  packages = {
    common = ./common;
    backend = ./backend;
    frontend = ./frontend;
    google-maps-reflex = ./google-maps-reflex;
  };

  shells = {
    ghc = ["common" "backend" "frontend" "heist"]; # "backend" "frontend"];
    ghcjs = ["common" "frontend"];
  };
})
```